# What does the operator | do to vec3 in boost::la?

Tags: boost

I'm trying to understand how this piece of code works. Here, the vector `theta` is being defined and is then used to calculate a rotation matrix.

I can't figure out how the `theta|Z` syntax works. My guess is it does something like `theta.z` - but I can't pinpoint which part of the boost source is doing this. Is this standard boost syntax?

The boost source for this is here: http://ci.boost.org/svn-trac/browser/sandbox/la/boost/la

Any hints/clues on this would be appreciated.

```
#include <boost/la/all.hpp>
using namespace boost::la;
typedef vec<double, 2> vec2;
typedef vec<double, 3> vec3;
typedef vec<double, 33> mat33;

// Actual code
vec3 *theta = ...
mat33 R = rotz_matrix<3>(-*theta|Z) * roty_matrix<3>(*theta|X) * rotx_matrix<3>(*theta|Y);
```

Comment: looks like it's not even boost. Could you at least drop the _name_ of the "la" library you're actually referring to? And the question seems to be "What does the `operator |` do for a `vec3` in <library name>?"

Comment: Updated the question title.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef vec<double, 33> mat33;
```

vec is a custom struct defined in http://ci.boost.org/svn-trac/browser/sandbox/la/boost/la/vec.hpp

From the code there:

```
template <class T,int D>
                struct
                vec
                        {
                        T a[D];
```

So T = double for type
   D = 33 for dimension

vec represents a vector of 33 doubles. It seems to be called a matrix which has total 33 elements in it.

```
// Actual code
mat33 R = rotz_matrix<3>(-*theta|Z) * roty_matrix<3>(*theta|X) * rotx_matrix<3>(*theta|Y);
```

This I am still trying to figure out. Where is rotz_matrix() declared ?